# Group data frame by week while preserving a week id

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have data structured like this:

```
library('dplyr')
library('lubridate')

set.seed(808)

date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by='day'), 100)
vals <- sample(seq(1, 375), 100)

df <- data.frame(date, vals)
df <- df[order(as.Date(df$date, format='%Y-%m-%d')),]
```

I know how to group by week and how to do some calculations with the grouped data:

```
df_agg <- df %>% group_by(week = week(date)) %>% summarise(value = na.omit(mean(vals)))
```

This returns a new data frame which has a column 'week' but the numbers in this column doesn't indicate which week in which year it is. So instead of week 1, 2, 3... etc. I want to have a unique id for each week (eg. 01-2015 for the first week in 2015).

Why do I want that?
I'm dealing with multiple data sets with different temporal solution and which I try to combine with each other. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about add year to groups?

```
    df %>%
      mutate(year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
      group_by(year, week = week(date)) %>% 
      summarise(value = na.omit(mean(vals))) %>%
      mutate(id = paste(year, "-",week))
```

result is like

```
    # A tibble: 90 x 4
    # Groups:   year [6]
        year  week value id       
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
     1  2015     2    66 2015 - 2 
     2  2015     3   331 2015 - 3 
     3  2015     7   372 2015 - 7 
     4  2015    10   226 2015 - 10
     5  2015    11   176 2015 - 11
     6  2015    13     4 2015 - 13
     7  2015    14   164 2015 - 14
     8  2015    18   339 2015 - 18
     9  2015    20    59 2015 - 20
    10  2015    26     1 2015 - 26
    # ... with 80 more rows
```

Comment: OP seems to want no space between `year` and `week`. So it'd be `paste0(year, "-", week)`.